# How do get Hmisc latex function to show only table contents

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

Running `latex(rnorm(5),file="")` through the `Hmisc` package will display both the contents of the table; for example:

```
$-0.8036409661674679$\tabularnewline
$ 1.2066652279406598$\tabularnewline
```

but it will also show the table preamble and ending; for example:

```
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

How do I force the command to *only* show the formatted contents of the table and *not* the table preamble/ending?

```
require(Hmisc)
latex(rnorm(5),file="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see `?Hmisc::latex` for arguments values. You can supress `table` and `center` environment without rewriting function:

```
> latex(rnorm(5),file="", table.env=FALSE, center="none", multicol=FALSE)
% latex.default(rnorm(5), file = "", table.env = FALSE, center = "none",      multicol = FALSE) 
%
\begin{tabular}{r}
\hline\hline
\tabularnewline
\hline
$ 0.170715837013809$\tabularnewline
$ 1.825384093014966$\tabularnewline
$-0.390987768400953$\tabularnewline
$ 1.429885144215387$\tabularnewline
$-0.505248111252067$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

`Hmisc::format_df` function will give you the desired result:

```
> x <- format.df(rnorm(5))
> cat(paste(x, "\\\\", collapse="\n"))
$ 0.184705304659614$ \\
$-1.570758868384333$ \\
$ 0.442248007654160$ \\
$-0.317095653252702$ \\
$ 0.160679032355016$ \\
```